# How to solve $ z^3=x^6+3x^3ay+3a^2y^2+by^3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y,a,b$ be nonzero integers with $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(a,b)=1$. I am trying to find all integer $z$ so that:
    $$z^3=x^6+3x^3ay+3a^2y^2+by^3$$

What I have done:
$$(z-x^2)[(z-x^2)^2+3(z-x^2)x^2+3x^4]=y(3ax^3+3a^2y+by^2)$$
Put $y=rs$
$$z=x^2+rp$$
$$(rp)^2+3(rp)x^2+3x^4=sq$$
$$3ax^3+3a^2rs+b(rs)^2=pq$$
Then
$$(3rp)^2+12(sq-(rp)^2)=(3d)^2$$
I feel like I am not on the right track. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't give me the classical answer $x=a=b=1$

Comment: Here's a nontrivial solution found using Mathematica: $a= -3368, b =-1, x = -1, y = -34, z =3401$, so they do exist. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: $(x^{2} + \frac{a}{x})^{3}= x^{6} + 3ax^{2}y + 3a^{2}y^{2} + \frac{a^{3}}{x^{3}} y^{3}$. One wonders if the given conditions can be manipulated to show that the $\frac{a}{x}$ is indeed an integer.

Comment: @rogerl, I am currently working on a paper. This equation is essential to prove the next steps. I am kind of stuck at this point unless someone bails me out :)

Comment: The last equation implies $4qs=(pr)^2+3d^2$, and hence (I think?) every prime on the left-hand side must be of the form $u^2+3v^2$. Maybe that helps?

Alternatively, consider $p^2r^2+3d^2-4qs=0$ and use a parameterization (_e.g._ Cauchy) to characterize the integers.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. My main concern is $pq$ at this point. It looks like I will have to the square of $x^3$ to replace $x^2$. If I don’t have an identity then I have to solve the resulting equation, which does not look too friendly. That’s why I question my method.